# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Dynamic display model fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

If we create a default ASP.NET Core 1.0 project, we have the default RegisterViewModel like this:

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming I create 2 more properties called FirstName, LastName how can I make it so that i can define dynamically what columns to be shown when user register's? Example I want to show: Email, Password, ConfirmPassword and FirstName. LastName should not be shown. And I don't mean add/remove from view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HiddenInput attribute on the property that you don't want to display, like this:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public string LastName {get; set;}
```

Comment: How can I set programmatically DisplayValue = false/true ?